# Continuous page no's in BO webi reports with multiple tabs

Tags: business-objects

I have BO web I report with multiple tabs lets take. ``` Tab 1=10 pages.
Tab 2=2 pages.``
Tab 3=3 pages ```.
While downloading report in to PD F in footer of the reports it should say page 1/15 2/15 3/15,----15/15 
but now it is showing as page 1/10 2/10,3,10----10/10 for first Tab ,second tab 1/2 ,2/2 and Third tab 1/3,2/3,/3/3

Can anybody please provide solution for the task

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mention the version of SAP BusinessObjects you're using, I'm going to assume BI 4.1.

There are only two page-related functions available: `NumberOfPages()` and `Page()`. As `NumberOfPages()` only returns the value for the current report, I'm afraid there's no way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Of course, you could always create a formula and add the `NumberOfPages()` to the total number of pages of the previous report (tab).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, unless the number of pages on a tab is fixed, it doesn't appear to be possible to know the previous tab's final page count when starting on a new tab. The `NumberOfPages()` function is limited to only referencing the current active tab, and forcing processing order to manually create a running page count variable doesn't seem to be possible.  Kristof's idea of creating a variable to add the previous tab's `NumberOfPages()` to the current tab's `Page()` result seems to not work.  There is some discussion on the BOB forums of doing just that, without success.

```
Var Tab1Pages = NumberOfPages()

Var Tab2Pages = Tab1Pages+Page()
```

When Tab2Pages resolves, it does not reference Tab1Pages' previously calculated result from tab1, but instead executes the `NumberOfPages()` function for the current tab and adds the current page number to that result.

The best solution I've seen so far is a bit of a cheat, but should work - break up your page numbering into report sections based on the tab.  Tab 1 would be numbered with the formula `="1."+Page()`, Tab 2 would be `="2."+Page()`, etc - giving your final output the page numbers 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3...